# Word used in English, though actually French, for "the art of mixing lab science with field work"

Tags: single-word-requests

I have been told that there is a word, probably starting with B, coined in French, probably by Louis Pasteur, though used in English, which has the following meaning:

> The successful blending of closed, lab based science with experience and knowledge of the limitations in enacting that same science in the field

What is the word?

Comment: Now that's a challenging SWR !

Comment: Perhaps here (none under B) http://en.citizendium.org/wiki/French_words_in_English/Catalogs

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Are you thinking of *bricolage*?

[Bricolage](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bricolage)

*In the practical arts and the fine arts, bricolage (French for "tinkering") is the construction or creation of a work from a diverse range of things that happen to be available, or a work created by such a process.*

*The term bricolage has also been used in many other fields, including critical theory, education, computer software, and business.*

Comment: not a bad guess, shame it was downvoted. (The only french B words that come to mind for me are "Bourgogne" and "Bourdeaux"  :O )

Comment: Quite often the downvote is a petty attack on the commentor, not on the comment.

Comment: That's the one!

Comment: You're kidding Dave!  that's AWESOME.  Pasteur, eh.  I did not know.  Amazing psyhic call of the day by Roaring.

Comment: No proof yet on Pasteur, but definitely a French :)

Comment: @RoaringFish: You misspelt "rarely".

Comment: @DaveRGP “Bricolage” seems to fit but be aware that the meaning is not nearly as specific in French (it can mean “tinkering”, “DIY” but also “bad work” or “quick fix”) and the word certainly wasn't coined to mean “mixing lab science with field work”.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ~ where did I write 'rarely'?

Comment: @RoaringFish: You didn't. You made a spelling mistake and wrote "often" instead.